# Fade In and Out on scroll using CSS opacity and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div element that I would like to have fade in a certain scroll point, but instead of using (slow) or (fast) properties I have used the CSS opacity, that way it will still be visible while you scroll and change opacities as you go up and down the page. This is used in the top logo and works perfect, but for some reason I cannot find a solution to use it again on the second logo. You can see it in use on my site so far here:
http://abezieleniec.com/SIDWeb

HTML

```
<div class="jumbotronsecond">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="biglogo2">
      <img src="images/biglogofull.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.biglogo2 {
width:80%;
display:block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:130px;
margin-bottom:130px;
opacity:1;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(function(){
    var fadeBegin = 500, 
    fadeFinish = 800, 
    fadingElement = $('.biglogo2');

    $(window).bind('scroll', function(){
       var offset = $(document).scrollTop(), opacity = 0; 
        if( offset <= fadeBegin ){
           opacity = 1; 
       } else if( offset <= fadeFinish ){
           opacity = 1 - offset / fadeFinish;
       }
     fadingElement.css('opacity',opacity);
    });
```

Comment: Could you please post the relevant code in your question?

Comment: @popnoodles Added the code for you to look at!

Answer (score 0):

On second thoughts it's a good thing you posted a link

```
<script src="js/vendor/jquery-scrollspy.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

You're loading the jQuery library AFTER the extension that requires it to exist. If you look at your console (in Chrome f12 then click console) you would see `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`

Your code works fine, except what you provided isn't balanced - there needs to be another `});` to close that `$(function(){`. I've indented your code to show this. I wasn't so tidy in the jsfiddle sorry.

http://jsfiddle.net/xtqLz/

To make the animation smoother replace this line

```
// fadingElement.css('opacity',opacity);
fadingElement.stop().animate({opacity: opacity}, 200);
```

This tells jQuery to animate the element to the next opacity, but each time `.stop()`s the previous animation, otherwise they queue.

http://jsfiddle.net/xtqLz/2/

Comment: I closed the function and added it to my site, but if you take a look you can see it 'snap' into a different opacity instead of smoothly changing, why do you think that is?

Comment: Because the scroll event makes leaps. Use the jsfiddle and open your console and look at the values as you scroll.  This could possibly be overcome, I will try...

Comment: By the way I don't struggle to read upside down. My brain reads that logo as "pis". Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It definitely works, I'm just curious as to why it works so smoothly at the top logo, but not as smooth at the middle logo.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Not sure actually.

Comment: Ok, it's this http://jsfiddle.net/xtqLz/4/ the elements need to calculate their own distance from the top and behave independently. You have to consider the margin too. My offset calculation is wrong though, it needs to work out the percentage between the start and end position. It's too late in the day for maths!

Comment: Ah you're much closer though! I will mess around with this and see if I can get it to work. Thanks again for all the help!